# Extract result using PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl

I am using PHP curl to get the Oauth tokens from the URL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Authorization: ' . oauth_headers($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $token, $token_secret, $verifier)));curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

https://www.yammer.com/oauth/request_token

Then, I got a response in the following way:

output

```
-------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2012 10:32:47 GMT
.........
.........

oauth_token=6y33AOcKOJVRVRggumfa9Q&oauth_token_secret=usjLakBRQh3Cq4rTWT1aJe9NVo7XKiATYIWvvVovI&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

How do i extract `oauth_token_secret` and `oauth_token` from the result?

Comment: It should be in XML format , can you share the code you're using please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `parse_str()`.

change `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `false` and then:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$string = parse_str($result);
echo $oauth_token_secret;
echo '<br />--------<br />';
echo $oauth_token;
```

Comment: But i am getting only $oauth_token_secret. please help me

Comment: add something before, i'll update my answer, but it should add `$oauth_token` as well

Comment: I try to inserting breaks, but no luck

Comment: can you post the result you get after changing `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `false` ?

Comment: Exactly what I said in the second line.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the answer you're getting, you'll probably want to have the oauth-... sting which will be after a double newline ("\n")

So then you could do:

```
parse_str(substr($s, strpos($s, "\n\n"));
echo $oauth_token_secret;
echo $oauth_token;
```

You can also try this to see what is parsed:

```
parse_str(substr($s, strpos($s, "\n\n"), $test);
var_dump($test);
```

Comment: But i am getting only $oauth_token_secret but not other

Comment: added another example, so you can see what is parsed.